# Works fine in debug, but having error when in release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit, reportviewer

May I know what is the meaning and how to solve this error? My project works fine when in debug mode but it contains errors when in release mode. How do I solve this? Thank You.

```
System.OperationCanceledException: Script entries not loaded yet.    
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: Script entries not loaded yet.
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.IsScriptRegistered(ScriptReference scriptReference)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnResolveScriptReference(ScriptReferenceEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe a bug http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27517